# Do hard disks spin and will read and write heads move when browsing?

Tags: hard-drive

For example, if i am loading and playing a browser based game on google chrome or refreshing a website on my laptop, is the hard drive active? (platters rotating/read and write heads moving). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**SPIN:** Unless you have a power setting to turn your drive off, it will always be spinning. Normal. If your website activity updates and retrieves favorites, the drive will spin.

**MOVE HEADS:**  Any write (update favorite, game setting) or any read (retrieve favorite or retrieve setting) will move the head (means the drive is spinning).  Normal.

Most of the time - activities above, registry updates - cause both spinning and head movement.

All this is entirely normal activity.

**Open Admin Tools**, Resource Monitor and make sure the DISK section is open. Let it run for 10 minutes and you will see the constant disk activity.

Here is a screen shot of an X230 with a hard drive. See the disk activity in the disk section.

[image]